# How to select a column of the last row in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select-query

I have to **enter a value of the last row of a table to another table**.Therefore within the insert query i've used to select query to get the value i want. The **query executes without any error**. But **it gives the 1st row of the table** instead of the last row.

Here is my query

```
SELECT top 1 ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL
```

Comment: Without `ORDER BY` `TOP` is meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC
or
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY POST_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Last row depends upon your sorting order.

To make sure, you get correct result each time you can do something like this.

```
SELECT top 1 ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer i found it somehow. By the way thankx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's work if you change the order to Descending.

for example :

```
SELECT top 1 ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Comment: You can use `limit 1` too, if you want to select only 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ORDER BY clause to get your desired result.

If your table have an incremental ID Colum sort the table using that , else number ur table using some functions like row_ number and and sort the number column.

Assuming your table is having identity column id.

```
 SELECT top 1 ref_no
  FROM MASTER_CALL
  ORDER BY ID DESC
```

If you table don't have an identity column, use below script.

```
 with cte_1
 As ( SELECT ref_no, ROW_NUBER( ORDER BY (select 1)) RNO
  FROM MASTER_CALL)
 SELECT ref_no 
 FROM cte_1
  ORDER BY  RNO DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answe for this.
This is my query and it works perfectly.

```
SELECT top 1 ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL order by ref_no desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an indexed column let's say 'ref_no', then use

```
SELECT top 1 ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL order by ref_no desc
```

Or if you don't have such thing you'll have make extra column row_number() as follows:

```
select top 1 a.ref_no
from
(
    select SlNo=row_number() over(order by (select 1)), ref_no 
    from MASTER_CAL
) a
order by slno desc
```

Answer (score 0):

insert into temp table at the same time, and select from that

It works even if you don't have auto increment column

```
DECLARE @table table (id int)

INSERT INTO MASTER_CAL
OUTPUT inserted.id into @table
VALUES('XYZ')

SELECT id from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL ORDER BY ID DESC limit 0,1
```

I think your `AUTO_INCREMENT` field is `ID` and table name is `MASTER_CAL`.Then above code will help you to find last inserted row in this table.

Comment: Question is about SQL Server and You can not use limit in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In your table `ref_no` column set as `Identity Increment = 1` then you can try this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL ORDER BY ref_no DESC
```

This query gives exact result which you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this : `SELECT ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL ORDER BY ref_no DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: It gives an error. By the way i found an answer for this

Comment: ok, my bad. it should be `SELECT TOP 1 ref_no FROM MASTER_CAL ORDER BY ref_no DESC`